# getting interface names from dmesg lines

Tags: linux, scripting, bash, linux-networking

I have some lines like
[   17.440000] eth0: XYZCOMPANY ABC4353 802.11 Wireless Controller

[   17.540000] eth1: XYZCOMPANY ABC4353 802.11 Wireless Controller

[   17.640000] eth2: XYZCOMPANY ABC4353 802.11 Wireless Controller

I need to get eth0, eth1, eth2 into a variable in shell script.
As you can notice all the other lines like XYZCOMPANY ABC4353  remains constant.but interface name is keep changing.  I need to get those interface names into a variable.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks.
Small doubt..what happens if [ 17.640000] is present only attimes?

Because the solution given below always expect ethX to be the third field right?
But the time optional one and it may be absent too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will show `eth` and `wlan` addresses with any number of digits:

```
var=$(dmesg | grep -Eo '(eth|wlan)[[:digit:]]+')
```

If you don't need `wlan` you can remove the alternate. I'm not sure if the `eth` driver uses hex, but you can change "digit" to "xdigit" if it does and you need to allow for more than 10 intefaces.

Comment: Firstly thanks!
Is the variable a array ? I need to evaluate interfaces one by one like eth0 , eth1 etc.,

Comment: I can deal with it like an array like this :

for i in ${var[@]}; do
        echo "hi"
done

Comment: @kumar: You can do it without an array: `for i in $var; do echo "interface: $i"; done`. To make it an array, add a set of parentheses: `array=($(dmesg | grep -Eo '(eth|wlan)[[:digit:]]+'))`.

Answer (score 0):

That is to have something like "eth0: eth1: eth2" in your variable

```
var=`awk /./'{print $3}' lala `
echo $var
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution should be working too:

`var=$(dmesg | grep "eth[0-9]: [A-Za-z0-9 ]* 802.11 Wireless Controller" | awk '{ print substr($3,0,5) }')`